# Jboss Messaging. sending one message per time

Tags: jboss, messaging

We are using JBOSS 5.1.0, we using topic for storing our messages. And our client is making a durable subscription to get those messages.

Everything is working fine, but one issue is we are getting data from TCP client, we are processing and keeping it in topic, it is sending around 10 messages per second, and our client is reading one message at a time. There is a huge gap between that, and after sometime JBOSS Topic have many messages and it crashes saying out of memory.
IS there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the producer is producing 10x more messages than consumer can handle. If this situation is stable (not only during peak), this will never work.

If you limit the producer to send only one message per second (which is of course possible, e.g. check out [`RateLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html)), what will you do with extra messages on the producer side? If they are not queueing up in the topic, they will queue up on the producer side.

You have few choices:

- somehow tune your consumer to process messages faster, so the topic is never filled up
- tune the topic to use persistent storage. This is much better. Not only the topic won't store everything in memory, but you might also get transactional behaviour (messages are durable)
- put a queue of messages that you want to set to the topic and process one message per second. That queue must be persistent and must be able to keep more messages than the topic currently can

Comment: Hi, Is there anyway that consumer will read all the messages at once, rather reading one message per time.

Comment: @Ravi: the consumer can you several threads to process more than one message at a time. Also you can use intermediate component called [aggregator](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Aggregator.html) to combine messages on the fly.